# Setting NSURL in a different view. Value is nil on current view

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, nsurl

I assume my mistake is a very simple one, but alas here's the problem.

At the moment i'm trying to set my NSURL with this block from ViewControllerB

```
-(IBAction)changeUrl:(id)sender{

    globalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:
                  @"http://secretUrl.fileExstension"];

    viewControllerA *viewA = [[viewControllerA alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewControllerA" bundle:nil];

    viewA.globalURL = [[NSURL alloc] init];
    viewA.globalURL = globalURL;

    [viewA.globalURL release];



}
```

And meanwhile in viewControllerA i'm doing this.

```
if (globalURL == nil) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"LOL NSURL IS NIL!"  
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}
else
{

    // initates the request with set NSURL

}
```

So the main problem is that the NSURL is not properly keeping it's value while being passed between the views.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)changeUrl:(id)sender{

globalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:
              @"http://secretUrl.fileExstension"];

viewControllerA *viewA = [[viewControllerA alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewControllerA" bundle:nil];



// viewA.globalURL = [[NSURL alloc] init]; //allocate this init method for viewcontrollerA
viewA.globalURL = globalURL;

   // [viewA.globalURL release]; // Dont release here.



}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[viewA.globalURL release];
```

i think the above line causing problem.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldnt release your  `[viewA.globalURL release]` 
I am assuming your `globalURL` is having a retain property to it. Your local variable is a autoreleased object and hence you need not release it explicity. Doing so you are bringing your reference count to 0 and hence the value is lost.

Comment: Yes thanks. It seems that the problem as a negative reference-count.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are creating ViewControllerA within ViewControllerB. Is that your intention? If your goal is to communicate with an already existing ViewControllerA, then you aren't going about it quite in the right manner.  I've usually accomplished this sort of thing by having all my view controllers share a common parent (the app delegate for example), and then messaging eachother through that common parent.

Example:

```
    MyAppDelegate *app = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    app.viewControllerA.globalURL=globalURL;
```

Comment: My intention is not to create the ViewControllerA. My intentions is to instantiate the view to access the view's variables and set them. I'm sure my approach is far from standard, but i've done so in other views accessing other views variables and it has worked until now. 

Does this example you've posted have to be connected in the IB in any way or should this just be working?

Comment: The sample code you posted would be creating a new instance of ViewControllerA, so if you have another one that is already displayed, this is pretty likely to cause some problems. I typically don't use IB at all, so for that sample code all you would need is an @property'd @synthesize'd reference to your ViewControllerA. Also you'd probably want to import MyAppDelegate.h & ViewControllerA.h from your ViewControllerB.m file.